# .NET C# Unreachable code detected

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `MyTest.aspx.cs` and a class named `MyTestClass.cs`. 
See below code for `MyTestClass.cs`. It gives me a warning regarding `Unreachable code detected`. It underlines the word `con` in `con.Close();`

My program works fine, I'm just troubled with this kind of warning. I researched about it and I tried what I found on the internet but it won't work. I guess I'm missing something here.

```
public string Insert_Data(string NewCol1 , string NewCol2, string NewCol3, string NewCol4, double NewCol5)
        {

            con.Open();
            string CheckString = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table  " +
                                                   "WHERE col1= '" + NewCol1 + "' " +
                                                   "and col2= '" + NewCol2 + "' " +
                                                   "and col3= '" + NewCol3 + "' " +
                                                   "and col4= '" + NewCol4 + "' ";

            cmd = new SqlCommand(CheckString,con);
            int Count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            if (Count > 0)
            {
                return "Record Already Exists.";
            }
            else
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO my_table (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,getupdateDate) " +
                    " VALUES('" + NewCol1+
                    "','" + NewCol2+
                    "','" + NewCol3 +
                    "','" + NewCol4+
                    "'," + NewCol5+ ", GETDATE())", con);

                int temp = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return "Inserted Sucessfully";
            }

            con.Close();

        }
```

Comment: Before returning the value, you should close the connection in your if else

Comment: Thanks Hari and Grant Winney . I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Please, please spend some time reading about SQL injection and parameterized queries. Building up SQL queries using string concatenation is ___BAD___.

Comment: Hi @JLRishe , yes I know about SQL injection, I'm going to fix my code, it's not yet final, I just need the logic for my issue above. That's not my exact code. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See you have two code paths in your snippets, one is through if and the other is through else, you have `return` statements in both paths, so the code after else block will not be executed and that is the error message telling. you have few options to get this solved.

Best option:

```
public string Insert_Data(string NewCol1 , string NewCol2, string NewCol3, string NewCol4, double NewCol5)
{
   try
   {
        // your code here
        if (Count > 0)
        {
            return "Record Already Exists.";
        }
        else
        {
          // code here
            return "Inserted Sucessfully";
        }

   }
   catch
   {
        return "Error occured";
   }
   finally
   {
        con.Close();
   }
}
```

If you don't want to go with try..catch means you can use like this:

```
public string Insert_Data(string NewCol1 , string NewCol2, string NewCol3, string NewCol4, double NewCol5)
{
    string resultMessage;
    // your code here
    if (Count > 0)
    {
        resultMessage = "Record Already Exists.";
    }
    else
    {
       // code here
       resultMessage = "Inserted Sucessfully";
    }
    con.Close();
    return resultMessage;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a problem. Both branches of your `if` statement have `return` statements, so the `con.Close()` will never execute, and not closing your connection is a bad thing.

One way to address this is to use a `try...finally`. Additionally, you should make sure that the code creating the connection disposes of it when it's not needed anymore (typically the way to do this is to use a `using` block.

And as a side note, please, please spend some time reading about SQL injection and parameterized queries. Building up SQL queries using string concatenation is ***BAD***.

```
public string Insert_Data(string NewCol1 , string NewCol2, string NewCol3, string NewCol4, double NewCol5)
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        string CheckString = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table  " +
                                               "WHERE col1= '" + NewCol1 + "' " +
                                               "and col2= '" + NewCol2 + "' " +
                                               "and col3= '" + NewCol3 + "' " +
                                               "and col4= '" + NewCol4 + "' ";

        cmd = new SqlCommand(CheckString,con);
        int Count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        if (Count > 0)
        {
            return "Record Already Exists.";
        }
        else
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO my_table (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,getupdateDate) " +
                " VALUES('" + NewCol1+
                "','" + NewCol2+
                "','" + NewCol3 +
                "','" + NewCol4+
                "'," + NewCol5+ ", GETDATE())", con);

            int temp = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return "Inserted Sucessfully";
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers correctly identify the issue you asked about.  However, there is a bigger issue here:

The compiler is almost never wrong with such warnings.  Thus, if you get a warning and you don't expect it that almost certainly means your code is doing something you did not intend it to do--which almost certainly means you have a bug.

I have found only two ways to make the compiler issue false warnings:

It doesn't understand that two conditionals are the same test and thus doesn't consider code in the first conditional to have run in the second conditional.  Fix: Provide bogus initialization for the relevant variable(s)--preferably with values that will not work.

It doesn't understand when a set of conditionals working together have covered all possible cases and will consider that execution can fall through.  Fix: provide a bogus return or throw an exception.

Edit:  And one case where it doesn't understand it can't reach it:  Code after a Trace.Assert(false);  While this might seem stupid I'm looking at one right now--the method **should be** abstract but that would mean the class would have to be abstract--and it's a parent of some forms, Visual Studio itself will instantiate it.  Thus all the abstract methods that Visual Studio won't call immediately throw.